# Sitecore JSS with headless mode can be hosted in AWS

Tags: jss

If using sitecore JSS App with Headless SSR via sitecore-jss-proxy, can the Node.js app be hosted on AWS server?

Note did mention below, but not clear about AWS. I understand Sitecore install have some complication on AWS, so we will be using Azure for that.

Question is only for Node.js app with headless proxy.

Answer (score 3):

Put simply yes. The Node.JS / jss-proxy app can run anywhere really, but can most definitely run in AWS, Azure, a2 Hosting, anywhere where you can host JavaSciprt.

For fast interactions with Sitecore between AWS and Azure, you will need to set up a VPN Gateway from Azure to AWS (like a Site-to-Site IPSEC tunnel) for the proxy just to make sure that the Node.JS app can talk to Sitecore through a dedicated route and not rely on just public interfaces when in Connected mode.

Additionally, and for some background, there are no issues associated with running Sitecore in Amazon's AWS EC2 IaaS offerings. And JSS can run so long as you are using the Subscription licensing model from Sitecore, which is the model that Sitecore is encouraging everyone to utilize.

Comment: Thank you very much. We had problem on install in AWS due to sql server was not able to run in admin mode with sa user. Will definitely look again with EC2 Iaas.

Answer (score 1):

The node server can certainly be hosted in AWS, but you will have a gigantic delay as the node server makes API calls to the Sitecore server that is still in Azure.

On a side note, there are no major issues running Sitecore in AWS as long as you run the farm in IaaS. I have built entire farms in AWS before. But if you want PaaS, Azure is the only supported mode. Also you do not need PaaS for JSS. Only the proper license.